# scala compute difference

Tags: scala, datetime

I have a scala function:

It return an error, it do not accept the parameters in plusDays and minusDay, knowing that I added all the required import:

```
<console>:143: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.time.LocalDate
 required: String
             toEnd(rd1.toLocalTime) + jourOuvree(rd1.toLocalDate.plusDays(1), rd2.toLocalDate.minusDays(1)) * 8.hours + toStart(rd2.toLocalTime)
                                                                         ^
<console>:143: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.time.LocalDate
 required: String
             toEnd(rd1.toLocalTime) + jourOuvree(rd1.toLocalDate.plusDays(1), rd2.toLocalDate.minusDays(1)) * 8.hours + toStart(rd2.toLocalTime)
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: It seems like jourOuvree is expecting a String and not a LocalDate

Comment: The error is in jourOuvree, not in the parameters in plusDays and minusDay as you say. You should check your method signature

Comment: yes exactly thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in jourOuvree, not in the parameters in plusDays and minusDay as you say. You should check your method signature.

If your method jourOuvree requires a date in String format as it seems to be the case, you can call a `toString` after the `plusDays` method

Example:

Without toString:

```
rd1.toLocalDate.plusDays(1)
res1: java.time.LocalDate = 2018-04-05
```

With toString:

```
rd1.toLocalDate.plusDays(1).toString
res2: String = 2018-04-05
```

In your case:

```
jourOuvree(rd1.toLocalDate.plusDays(1).toString, rd2.toLocalDate.minusDays(1)).toString)
```